# Geonode : Morphing profil along a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I would like to morph the profil of a cuve so that it moves from geometry A to geometry B, from one end to the other.

I managed to produce a morphing geometry depending on one parameter this way :

[image: Morphing geonodes]

... but when I plug the Spline parameter's factor, I get no variation along the curve :

[image: pluging Spline parameter's factor]

I suspect that something in fundamentally wrong in the method ... or in the goal itself ...

Here is the file :

[image]

Thanks ...
for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hspace{15pt}$The Curve profile is the same for all points in the curve, as it is evaluated only once. For that to work it would first need that Blender supported $\color{MediumSpringGreen}♦$ geometry fields.

$\hspace{15pt}$One of the things you can do is calculate both of the profiles, capturing the spline factor in one so that it passes to the resulting mesh, and then mix the position using the captured attribute as factor.

[image: node tree]

[image: result]

Comment: Great !! Thank you Hulifier. You solved my problem and taught me something useful ...